# How can I see the classes on the java classpath at runtime in a non-maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, classpath, classloader

I have two projects with the same declared dependencies in eclipse. One set of unit tests work, and the other set does not. I am getting an error `No tests matching [*methodname*]`. Some googling suggests library issues, but I have not been able to identify where those could be getting introduced. The projects are almost identical and the test framework (junit, powermock, mockito) should be identical. Viewing the java build path in preferences -> java build path shows the same references. I'm suspecting that eclipse menus are not reflecting the actual classes being loaded at runtime. Is there a way to echo out the classpath at runtime so I can scan it for duplicates?

update: the underlying issue was that I had conflicting versions of junit and powermock on the classpath. I was able to resolve this by removing, re-adding, and re-ordering jars from the eclipse build path config panel. This was very tedious and the accepted solution below would have significantly reduced the resolution time.

this question was flagged as a duplicate, but the linked article is specific to maven, and doesn't address the underlying problem of seeing a classpath at runtime. the accepted solution is viable for maven and non-maven projects.

Comment: Are you using an additional library like JUnitParams? I had a similar issue just yesterday, the reason for me was that the parameter preparation code threw an exception and eclipse showed that as 'no tests matching'.

Comment: The classpath of a project and of a launch/run configuration can differ. Do the two launch/run configurations have the same classpath?

Comment: if you used a real dependency management system like Maven, Gradle or even Ivy you would not have these issues.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson i am imminently aware of this. review my other posts to confirm. We work within the constraints we are provided.

@howlger that is what I am trying to investigate. i am running unit tests in eclipse via `right click > run as > junit test`. how would I review the configuration for these runs?

@Absurd-Mind turns out the underlying problem was that I had conflicting versions of powermock and junit on my path. I suspected as much, but it was a lot of guess and check within the build path to see where the conflicting versions were introduced.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several ways of investigating the actual classpath at runtime:

- Run your JVM with `-verbose:class`. This will produce output like so:

  ```
  [Loaded java.lang.Object from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
  [Loaded java.io.Serializable from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
  ```
- Run the following code within your JVM:

  ```
  ClassLoader classloader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

  URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) classloader).getURLs();

  for (URL url : urls) {
      System.out.println(url.getFile());
  }
  ```